# Flutter Date FormatException

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

---

A FormatException occurs when I tried to format date.

```
    final _filterDateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").add_Hm();
    Future<List<Data>> loadData(
  Filter filter,
) async {
  Uri path = createUri(
  Path,
    {
      "start_date": _filterDateFormat.format(filter.fromDate!)
    })
}
```

FormatException: Trying to read . from 8 00:00:00.04.2023 at position  3

Exception Occurs in this line:"start_date": _filterDateFormat.format(filter.fromDate!)

Answer (score 0):

The FormatException error is occurring because the DateFormat you have specified doesn't match the format of the input date. The DateFormat you specified is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", but the input date seems to be in the format "HH:mm:ss.dd.yyyy" change your code to something like:

```
final _filterDateFormat = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss.dd.yyyy").add_Hm();
```